# Fast way to turn dictionary to (dense) matrix

Tags: python, numpy, sage

I have a list of dictionaries, with values always integers, and keys some strings. We can interpret this as a matrix, where each dictionary is a row, and each column corresponds to a key belonging to at least one of the dictionaries. The dictionaries represent polynomials, where the keys are monomials and the values the coefficients.

For example, `[{'x':1, 'y':1, 'z':2}, {'x': 2}, {'y':1, 'z':3}]` corresponds to matrix:

```
[ 1 1 2,
  2 0 0,
  0 1 3 ]
```

I do this operation very frequently, and I need a high performance solution. The matrices are not very large, so I need a solution minimizing overhead. Currently some computation spends about a third of the time on this vectorizing of dictionaries.

This basically corresponds to `sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer`. I'm working in sagemath, which does not ship with sci-kit learn, so using this is not ideal. Furthermore `DictVectorizer` builds a sparse matrix and then turns it into a dense matrix. I tried this approach myself, and it turns out to be slower due to the large extra overhead.

My current algorithm is the following:

```
def dictionary_vectorizer(list_of_dicts):
    # Make a list of all the keys occurring in the dictionaries
    keys = set()
    for dic in list_of_dicts:
        for key in dic.keys():
            keys.add(key)

    # Create a mapping keys -> column_index
    key_map = {key: index for index, key in enumerate(keys)}

    output = np.zeros((len(list_of_dicts), len(keys)))
    for row_number, dic in enumerate(list_of_dicts):
        for key, value in dic.items():
            output[row_number, key_map[key]] = value

    return output
```

In my actual code I use sagemath's `matrix` constructor instead of np.zeros, but it doesn't change much. It seems like initializing a matrix of zeros, and then editing the rows is not the fastest way to do this. Computing the matrix row by row and then concatenating the results gives the same speed.

Is there an obvious way to speed this up (while keeping a low overhead)?

Comment: Sparse matrix creation is not known for being fast.  A `dok` matrix is a subclass of `dict`, but does not implement `update` (because it wants to verify values).  Once created the `dok` still has to be converted to `csr` format, and then `toarray()`.  Given the non-conventional nature of your mapping I think your code is as good as you'll get.

Comment: You can use `keys = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(e.keys() for e in a))` to shave off a bit of overhead

Comment: How do you define the mapping between keys and column indices? Is it a lexicographic order?

Comment: The order is not relevant for the specific problem. In any case it seems that populating the matrix is what costs the most time, not finding the set of keys.

Answer (score 0):

If, according to this part of the question:

> This basically corresponds to `sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer`.
>   I'm working in sagemath, which does not ship with sci-kit learn, so using
>   this is not ideal.

the wish is to install scikit-learn into SageMath, then depending
on how Sage was installed, it might suffice to run in a terminal:

```
$ sage --pip install scikit-learn
```

Then one can do the following in Sage:

```
sage: data = [{'x':1, 'y':1, 'z':2}, {'x':2}, {'y':1, 'z':3}]
sage: data
[{'x': 1, 'y': 1, 'z': 2}, {'x': 2}, {'y': 1, 'z': 3}]

sage: from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
sage: v = DictVectorizer(dtype=int, sparse=False)
sage: X = v.fit_transform(data)
sage: print(X)
[[1 1 2]
 [2 0 0]
 [0 1 3]]
```

If the goal is just to speed up the code in the question,
skipping the creation of the key-to-column-index mapping
might make things slightly faster, though not drastically.

```
def dictionary_vectorizer(list_of_dicts):
    # List all keys occurring in the dictionaries
    keys = set(key for dic in list_of_dicts for key in dic)
    # Initialize zero array of correct shape
    output = np.zeros((len(list_of_dicts), len(keys)))
    # Set nonzero entries
    for row_number, dic in enumerate(list_of_dicts):
        for col_number, key in enumerate(keys):
            if key in dic:
                output[row_number, col_number] = dic[key]
    return output
```

If the function is applied to a large quantity of data
which share the same monomials, it might make sense to
separate out the detection of the keys.

One could think of re-using a same array, passing it
as an argument, to save the cost of creating a new
numpy array. Not sure that would help much.

If using a list of dictionaries is limiting, one might
also think of changing the data production step.

Cython or Pythran might help speed this further.

Comment: Looking at the source code of `DictVectorizer`, it builds a sparse matrix and if `sparse=False` it calls the `.toarray()` method to turn it into a dense matrix. The extra overhead of building a sparse matrix is not worth it in my situation. I mainly linked to DictVectorizer as an example of what kind of output I expected. I edited the question to hopefully make my intend more clear.